# How to effectively combine a list of NumericVectors into one large NumericVector?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote the following Rcpp code which compiles, but the speed is not fast as expected.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector combine_list_to_vec (const Rcpp::List& list)
{
  int list_size = list.size();
  int large_vec_size = 0;
  IntegerVector start_index(list_size);
  IntegerVector end_index(list_size);
  for (int ii = 0; ii < list_size; ii++)
  {
    NumericVector vec = list[ii];
    start_index[ii] = large_vec_size;
    large_vec_size += vec.size();
    end_index[ii] = large_vec_size - 1;
  }
  NumericVector large_vec(large_vec_size);   // Creating object after getting its size
  for (int ii = 0; ii < list_size; ii++)
  {
    int current_start_index = start_index[ii];
    NumericVector vec = list[ii];
    for (int jj = 0; jj < vec.size(); jj++)
    {
      large_vec[jj + current_start_index] = vec[jj];
    }
  }
  return large_vec;
}
```

The input variable 'list' contains a bunch of NumericVector, and I want to combine them into a large one, with '...tail - head -tail...' structure. The start_index and end_index variables are used to facilitate copy.

The microbenchmark test gives the following info for a specific example:

```
x=list();
x[[1]]=runif(1E6);  x[[2]]=runif(1E6);
x[[3]]=runif(1E6);  x[[4]]=runif(1E6);
x[[5]]=runif(1E6);  x[[6]]=runif(1E6);
x[[7]]=runif(1E6);  x[[8]]=runif(1E6);
x[[9]]=runif(1E6);  x[[10]]=runif(1E6);
microbenchmark(combine_list_to_vec(x) -> y)

# Unit: milliseconds
                        expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
# y <- combine_list_to_vec(x) 84.166964 84.587516 89.9520601 84.728212 84.871673 349.33234   100
```

Another way that I tried is to call external R function `do.call(c,x)`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List combine_list_to_vec (const Rcpp::List& list)
{
  int list_size = list.size();
  int large_vec_size = 0;
  IntegerVector start_index(list_size);
  IntegerVector end_index(list_size);
  for (int ii = 0; ii < list_size; ii++)
  {
    NumericVector vec = list[ii];
    start_index[ii] = large_vec_size;
    large_vec_size += vec.size();
    end_index[ii] = large_vec_size - 1;
  }
  NumericVector large_vec = internal::convert_using_rfunction(list, "sub_do_call");
  List rtn = List::create(large_vec, start_index, end_index);
  return rtn;
}

// The following codes exist as R codes instead of Rcpp
sub_do_call <- function (x)
{
  return (do.call(c, x));
}
```

The speed is almost 4 times faster than previous code. Is there any way that can speedup the combination operation by using pointer or other tools in Rcpp and/or RcppArmadillo, or simply code do.call(c,x) in Rcpp instead of calling it externally? Thank you.

Comment: You are timing an optimized build, right?  If it isn't an optimized build, then the results are meaningless.

Comment: For what it's worth, on my machine `xvec=do.call(c, x)` benchmarks at 34 ms (mean), while `combine_list_to_vec` benchmarks at 61 ms.

Comment: Yes, it is an optimized build. In this example, I am moving every element individually, I wonder is there any way to manipulate/move pointers to make  it faster...

Comment: @eipi10 I assume that `do.call()` was directly used in R environment. Since the above question is part of the subfunction in my rcpp codes, and I hope to solve it in rcpp if possible

Comment: @Alvin, then you should state what compiler flags you used when you compiled your example, so that everyone is aware of this.  There are a *lot* of questions asked about the speed of programs, with all going to nothing because the poster didn't run a release or optimized program.

Comment: Yes, `do.call` was within `R`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Here, in Rstudio I use the Rcpp compiler with   `Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/Test_1.cpp')` . As far as I know, it is an optimized one

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Compiler settings are stored from when R (which assumes the role of a shell here) is configured and built and _can be assumed to be constant_ across experiments.

Comment: @eipi10 I tried to call `do.call()` in Rcpp by using `internal::convert_using_rfunction(x, "sub_do_call")` where `sub_do_call` is a `do.call()` function in R `sub_do_call <- function (x) {return (do.call(c, x))}`. After microbenchmark for the same test, it shows 27.3ms (mean) on my machine. I am thinking that how the source codes of `do.call(c,x)` (maybe in C++, Rcpp...) works so that I can code directly in Rcpp to make it faster instead of calling external R function ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're basically asking, "how can I write `base::unlist` in `Rcpp`?" And, since `base::unlist` is an `.Internal` function (it has a C implementation) it's unlikely you'll be able to do better with `Rcpp`.

But, let's try anyway, for fun. Here's an implementation I would use that's similar to yours, but should be cheaper as we use `std::copy` rather than re-indexing on every iteration:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector combine(const List& list)
{
   std::size_t n = list.size();

   // Figure out the length of the output vector
   std::size_t total_length = 0;
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      total_length += Rf_length(list[i]);

   // Allocate the vector
   NumericVector output = no_init(total_length);

   // Loop and fill
   std::size_t index = 0;
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
      NumericVector el = list[i];
      std::copy(el.begin(), el.end(), output.begin() + index);

      // Update the index
      index += el.size();
   }

   return output;

}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- replicate(10, runif(1E6), simplify = FALSE)
identical(unlist(x), combine(x))
microbenchmark(
   unlist(x),
   combine(x)
)
*/
```

Running this code gives me:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('C:/Users/Kevin/scratch/combine.cpp')

> library(microbenchmark)

> x <- replicate(10, runif(1E6), simplify = FALSE)

> identical(unlist(x), combine(x))
[1] TRUE

> microbenchmark(
+    unlist(x),
+    combine(x)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  unlist(x) 21.89620 22.43381 29.20832 23.14454 35.32135 68.09562   100
 combine(x) 20.96225 21.55827 28.13269 22.08985 24.13403 51.68660   100
```

So, effectively the same. We gain a tiny bit of time just because we don't do any type checking (which means this code blows up if we don't have a list containing only numeric vectors) but should at least be illustrative of the fact that we really can't do much better here.

(the only exception, I guess, would be with *huge* vectors where parallel processing might be helpful here)