List to Vector in Rcpp
Is there an elementary function in Rcpp to transform a Rcpp::list object within Rcpp to a Rcpp::NumericVector? One way would be to import the unlist function of R, but thats not very elegant.

Could you show a short R example of what you have in mind?

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30201460/4002530
